# How to troubleshoot threading issues on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, pthreads

I am trying to debug a problem with an application on Linux. It tends to crash with SIGSEGV in random places at `libstdc++.so` or `libstdc.so`.

There seem to be no obvious race conditions anywhere, as the job in the thread I added is very isolated. But it still crashes almost all the time.

The application is compiled with `g++ -c ... -pthread -D_REENTRANT`, and linked with `g++ -pthread -o ...`

But it's still crashing almost all the time in one of the `libstdc*.so` functions. I have wasted a few days on trying to figure out what's wrong, but no go...

Does anyone have any tips? Is there a way to make sure `libstdc*.so` is compiled as thread aware? Any gdb commands that could help me? Debug heaps?

I'm working with Linux for only a few years, so I'm lost...

Comment: Can you post relevant sections of the code?

Comment: You want some mustard with that can of worms?

Comment: @hmjd: Unfortunately it's an already large code base, which is extended for multi-threading. I cannot create a reproduction scenario for a subset of that. Therefore I'm looking for techniques that could help, that's all I can do.

Comment: `... which is extended for multi-threading` - oh dear! Generally a bad move. Better to code having incorporated concurrency into the technical design, although I accept you have no control over that now. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few things you should do :

- run your application using [hellgrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#helgrind)
- run your application using [valgrind's memory check](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck)
- run your application using [DRD](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#drd)

Write unit tests. Although they do not help much in finding problems with threads, they can help you greatly with finding wrong memory access problems.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `-g` when compiling if you're not already, to get symbolic debugger info.

Do you get a core dumped? If so you can use `gdb` to load the core against the executable as follows:

```
gdb <my-exe> <my-core-file>
```

Once loaded (presuming you compiled with `-g`) you can use `info threads` to get a list of all the threads stacks and take a look at the thread which caused the problem. If you follow the stack trace which caused the seg fault back up from the `libstdc++.so` or `libstdc.so` it should be reasonbaly obvious what's happening. At least it will get you to the right area.

If you don't get a core, can you run your app within the debugger itself?

This technique is also very useful fo getting to the bottom of thread deadlocking: Simply attach to the process using:

```
gdb <my-exe> <my-process-id>
```

and look for the two threads which are locking each other.

Comment: I'm launching the app via `gdb myapp`, then `r`, `SIGSEGV`, `bt`, `info threads`. I have the call stacks, but they fail on `malloc`s and `new`s within `libstdc*.so`s

Comment: Sounds like either your runtime library installation got screwed up or there's an incompatibility between your build and runtime environments. Have you rebuilt everything from scratch and checked `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or equivalent?

Comment: sure, but what functions are calling the `malloc`s and `new`s? look in the call stack until you see functions that relate to your software stack, and are not just in the clib.